# group_names variable in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am running some issues when I execute this playbook:

```
- hosts: all
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - template: src=/etc/ansible/{{group_names}}/common.j2 dest=/etc/ansible/configs/{{inventory_hostname}}.txt
    name: create common config snippets
```

the error that I am getting is:

```
fatal: [R1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Unable to find '/etc/ansible/[u'ios']/common.j2' in expected paths."}
fatal: [R2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Unable to find '/etc/ansible/[u'ios1']/common.j2' in expected paths."}
```

and here are my groups:

```
/etc/ansible# cat hosts | grep ios           
[ios]
[ios1]
```

and here are my `common.j2` files:

```
/etc/ansible# ls ios1/
common.j2


/etc/ansible# ls ios/ 
common.j2
```

Could someone elaborate why the `group_names` returns `[u'group_names]` please?

Comment: `group_names` [is a list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts). It doesn't make sense to substitute it in a filename like that.

Comment: I am new to ansible , i did not know that and thanks so much for prompt answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `group_names` a list (that's why it is surrounded by `[ ]`) -- a host can belong to multiple groups.

You need to decide, what is your objective:

- If you wanted to include files for all groups, you have to add a loop:

  ```
  - hosts: all
    connection: local
    tasks:
      - name: create common config snippets
        template:
          src: /etc/ansible/{{item}}/common.j2
          dest: /etc/ansible/configs/{{inventory_hostname}}.txt
        with_items: "{{group_names}}"
  ```
- If you wanted to add a single group, you could refer to a single element (`group_names[0]`), but that doesn't seem practical...

Comment: you guys are amazing.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the order in which ansible populates `group_names` is defined anywhere, so I'd advise against relying on using `group_names[0]` to always yield the same group name.